# How can Meteor apps be tested?

Tags: testing, meteor, tdd

What are the recommended ways to test web applications developed with the [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) framework?

The [meteor unofficial FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-are-the-best-practices-for-test-driven-development) entry on TDD best practices is quite short.

Comment: Testing a Javascript framework is considered "off topic"?! Who would have thought...

Comment: Checkout laika - http://arunoda.github.io/laika/ it is based on mocha and you can do end to end testing much easier.

Comment: See also [Meteor test-driven development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987525/meteor-test-driven-development)

Answer (score 6):

Sebastian Maier has a repository where he created a meteor app and tests it with Jasmine. You could check it out, [here's a link](https://github.com/sebastianmaier/meteor-jasmine).

Comment: [Velocity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26523192/1269037), Meteor's official testing framework, was just released.

Answer (score 4):

The Meteor documentation is woefully and/or intentionally silent on the subject of testing, other than this one quote:

> Great care has been taken to give the core Meteor packages the minimal set of dependencies, so you can use your favorite templating, testing, or DOM manipulation frameworks.

So I guess you're free to test however you like, which is supposed to be a feature.

There are a number of fine testing tools that would be applicable to a Meteor webapp, [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) being one example.

Comment: I would love to see a continuously running unit testing framework which updates as you edit, just the meteor way of coding and effecting.

Comment: [Velocity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26523192/1269037), Meteor's official testing framework, was just released.

Answer (score 2):

With [v0.9.4, released Oct 13, 2014](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/10/13/meteor-094-mobile-and-testing), Meteor has an official test framework, [meteor-velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity). It supports Jasmine, Mocha and Selenium.

```
meteor run --test
```

The architect behind Velocity has published a book, [Meteor Testing](http://www.meteortesting.com/).

See also http://velocity.meteor.com/